# Empty Struct on Response

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct, slice

I have a query which casts into a struct. But when the query returns no results the response is `null` - how do I get this to be an empty array `[]`?

```
_, err := dbmap.Select(&response.DevTeam, "SELECT * FROM DevTeam WHERE app_id = ? LIMIT ? OFFSET ?", a_id, limit, offset)
```

Response when no results:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "meta": "success"
}
```

Desired response when no results:

```
{
  "data": [],
  "meta": "success"
}
```

Still getting null - my struct setup is:

```
type HttpResonse struct {
    DevTeam []DevTeam `json:"data"`
}
```

I am using `response.DevTeam = []models.DevTeam{}` as suggested below but still getting `null`.

Response section:

```
s.Count = int64(len(response.DevTeam))  
c.JSON(httpcode, gin.H{"meta": s, "data": response.DevTeam})
```

Answer (score 1):

A value of slice type being `nil` encodes as the `null` JSON object. A non-`nil` empty slice is marshaled into an empty array `[]`.

Before marshaling `response`, check the `DevTeam` field, and if it's `nil`, explicitly set a slice value with `0` length, e.g.:

```
if response.DevTeam == nil {
   response.DevTeam = []models.DevTeam{} 
}
```

Or alternatively when you create your `gin.H` wrapper, use an empty slice instead of `response.DevTeam` if the latter equals to `nil`.

See this simple example:

```
type Pt struct {
    DevTeam []string
}

p := Pt{}
json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(p)

p.DevTeam = []string{}
json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(p)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cHmuZoKEAG)):

```
{"DevTeam":null}
{"DevTeam":[]}
```

Comment: see above for my setup

Comment: @ElliotReeve You're still not showing everything. Where does the `"meta"` come from in the result JSON for example?

Comment: I have updated to show the meta section and c.JSON output

Comment: @ElliotReeve Then it looks like the `response` whose `DevTeam` field you set to an empty slice and the one you encode are not the same!